# DatagridView is not getting data from the DataSource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource, oledb

I'm currently working on a programm in which I can generate Keys and save them into a locally created access Database, which does work. But when I try to View those generated keys in a DataGridView, the DataGridView stays blank.

I have already tried to set breakpoints, and the sql command is right

This is my Sub which I want to use to fill the DataGridView

```
Friend Sub FillDGV(ByVal sTable As String)

        Dim VDB As New OleDbConnection(getProviderString)
        Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM " & sTable
        Dim DBDataadapter As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim DBDataset As New DataSet
        Dim DBDatatable As New DataTable
        resetDGV()

        Try
            VDB.Open()
            DBDataadapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, VDB)
            DBDataadapter.Fill(DBDataset, SQLString)

            DBDataadapter.Dispose()
            VDB.Close()

            frmMain.dgv_Voucher.DataSource = DBDataset.Tables(sTable)  'Tabelle an DataSource binden

            VDB.Dispose()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            frmMain.LogMessage(modMain.msv_sAppname_Short & ", während der Prüfung der Existenz der Tabelle " & modMain.sMSAccess_File_Name & ". Es kam zu folgender Exception : " & ex.Message, 3)
            If VDB IsNot Nothing Then VDB.Close()
        End Try


    End Sub
```

This is what I use to open the Sub

```
Private Sub cmb_SelectedDBTable_Index_changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmb_SelectedDBTable.SelectedIndexChanged
        db.FillDGV(cmb_SelectedDBTable.SelectedItem)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now, This is what I have done

```
Friend Sub TestFillDGV(ByVal sTable As String)
        Dim VDB As New OleDbConnection(getProviderString)
        Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM " & sTable
        Dim DBDataadapter As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim DBDataset As New DataSet
        resetDGV()

        Try
            VDB.Open()

            DBDataadapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, VDB)
            DBDataadapter.Fill(DBDataset, sTable)

            VDB.Close()

            frmMain.dgv_Voucher.DataSource = DBDataset
            frmMain.dgv_Voucher.DataMember = sTable
            frmMain.dgv_Voucher.Columns("voucher_ID").Visible = False

            VDB.Dispose()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            frmMain.LogMessage(modMain.msv_sAppname_Short & ", während der Prüfung der Existenz der Tabelle " & modMain.sMSAccess_File_Name & ". Es kam zu folgender Exception : " & ex.Message, 3)
            If VDB IsNot Nothing Then VDB.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
```